# Start scrolling div at 30px from top

Tags: javascript, html, css

Instead of posting an issue I am dropping this simple question. This because I can't find any similar codes or issues so it just might not be possible?
At worst I have been searching for the wrong keywords.

Is it possible and how to do this when at page load to have an scrolling div starting not on top but about 30px scrolled down?

```
<div class="panel-body" style="margin:0 auto; width:100%; height:555px;overflow: auto;">
    Big amount of info here
</div>
```

**Current situation:**

[image]

**But at pageload I would like:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this effect.

One **CSS-only** approach is to give the first child of the scrollable div a *negative top margin*, like this:

```
.scrollable-div :first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
```

---

**Working Example:**

```css
.scrollable-div {
 float: left;
 width: 160px;
 height: 180px;
 margin-right: 12px;
 padding: 12px;
 border: 1px solid rgb(191, 191, 191);
 overflow-y: scroll;
}

.red-square {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.offset :first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable-div">
  <div class="red-square"></div>
  <h2>Down the Rabbit-Hole</h2>

  <p>Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in it, “and what is the use of a book,” thought Alice “without pictures or conversations?”</p>

  <p>So she was considering in her own mind (as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid), whether the pleasure of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by her.</p>

  <p>There was nothing so very remarkable in that; nor did Alice think it so very much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to itself, “Oh dear! Oh dear! I shall be late!” (when she thought it over afterwards, it occurred to her that she ought to have wondered at this, but at the time it all seemed quite natural); but when the Rabbit actually took a watch out of its waistcoat-pocket, and looked at it, and then hurried on, Alice started to her feet, for it flashed across her mind that she had never before seen a rabbit with either a waistcoat-pocket, or a watch to take out of it, and burning with curiosity, she ran across the field after it, and fortunately was just in time to see it pop down a large rabbit-hole under the hedge.</p>

  <p>In another moment down went Alice after it, never once considering how in the world she was to get out again.</p>

  <p>The rabbit-hole went straight on like a tunnel for some way, and then dipped suddenly down, so suddenly that Alice had not a moment to think about stopping herself before she found herself falling down a very deep well.</p>

  <p>Either the well was very deep, or she fell very slowly, for she had plenty of time as she went down to look about her and to wonder what was going to happen next. First, she tried to look down and make out what she was coming to, but it was too dark to see anything; then she looked at the sides of the well, and noticed that they were filled with cupboards and book-shelves; here and there she saw maps and pictures hung upon pegs. She took down a jar from one of the shelves as she passed; it was labelled “ORANGE MARMALADE”, but to her great disappointment it was empty: she did not like to drop the jar for fear of killing somebody underneath, so managed to put it into one of the cupboards as she fell past it.</p>

  <p>“Well!” thought Alice to herself, “after such a fall as this, I shall think nothing of tumbling down stairs! How brave they’ll all think me at home! Why, I wouldn’t say anything about it, even if I fell off the top of the house!” (Which was very likely true.)</p>

  <p>Down, down, down. Would the fall never come to an end? “I wonder how many miles I’ve fallen by this time?” she said aloud. “I must be getting somewhere near the centre of the earth. Let me see: that would be four thousand miles down, I think—” (for, you see, Alice had learnt several things of this sort in her lessons in the schoolroom, and though this was not a very good opportunity for showing off her knowledge, as there was no one to listen to her, still it was good practice to say it over) “—yes, that’s about the right distance—but then I wonder what Latitude or Longitude I’ve got to?” (Alice had no idea what Latitude was, or Longitude either, but thought they were nice grand words to say.)</p>
</div>

<div class="scrollable-div offset">
  <div class="red-square"></div>
  <h2>Down the Rabbit-Hole</h2>

  <p>Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in it, “and what is the use of a book,” thought Alice “without pictures or conversations?”</p>

  <p>So she was considering in her own mind (as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid), whether the pleasure of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by her.</p>

  <p>There was nothing so very remarkable in that; nor did Alice think it so very much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to itself, “Oh dear! Oh dear! I shall be late!” (when she thought it over afterwards, it occurred to her that she ought to have wondered at this, but at the time it all seemed quite natural); but when the Rabbit actually took a watch out of its waistcoat-pocket, and looked at it, and then hurried on, Alice started to her feet, for it flashed across her mind that she had never before seen a rabbit with either a waistcoat-pocket, or a watch to take out of it, and burning with curiosity, she ran across the field after it, and fortunately was just in time to see it pop down a large rabbit-hole under the hedge.</p>

  <p>In another moment down went Alice after it, never once considering how in the world she was to get out again.</p>

  <p>The rabbit-hole went straight on like a tunnel for some way, and then dipped suddenly down, so suddenly that Alice had not a moment to think about stopping herself before she found herself falling down a very deep well.</p>

  <p>Either the well was very deep, or she fell very slowly, for she had plenty of time as she went down to look about her and to wonder what was going to happen next. First, she tried to look down and make out what she was coming to, but it was too dark to see anything; then she looked at the sides of the well, and noticed that they were filled with cupboards and book-shelves; here and there she saw maps and pictures hung upon pegs. She took down a jar from one of the shelves as she passed; it was labelled “ORANGE MARMALADE”, but to her great disappointment it was empty: she did not like to drop the jar for fear of killing somebody underneath, so managed to put it into one of the cupboards as she fell past it.</p>

  <p>“Well!” thought Alice to herself, “after such a fall as this, I shall think nothing of tumbling down stairs! How brave they’ll all think me at home! Why, I wouldn’t say anything about it, even if I fell off the top of the house!” (Which was very likely true.)</p>

  <p>Down, down, down. Would the fall never come to an end? “I wonder how many miles I’ve fallen by this time?” she said aloud. “I must be getting somewhere near the centre of the earth. Let me see: that would be four thousand miles down, I think—” (for, you see, Alice had learnt several things of this sort in her lessons in the schoolroom, and though this was not a very good opportunity for showing off her knowledge, as there was no one to listen to her, still it was good practice to say it over) “—yes, that’s about the right distance—but then I wonder what Latitude or Longitude I’ve got to?” (Alice had no idea what Latitude was, or Longitude either, but thought they were nice grand words to say.)</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `scrollTop()`: https://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var startPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('div').scrollTop(startPos + 30);
});
```

```css
div {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis quis dui vitae justo porttitor accumsan a nec eros. Aenean at lacus quam. Pellentesque placerat enim sit amet nunc pharetra commodo. Etiam pharetra vehicula laoreet. Donec condimentum quis mi a finibus. Quisque non est sit amet magna hendrerit sagittis dictum sit amet nibh. In blandit magna vitae turpis interdum fringilla.

Ut iaculis urna vitae velit congue egestas. Sed vehicula, tortor vel consectetur pharetra, ipsum nisi lobortis metus, at congue felis dolor at dolor. Maecenas ut lobortis purus. Suspendisse a feugiat enim. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Donec blandit lacus quis pulvinar malesuada. Donec ipsum quam, consequat sit amet sapien sed, blandit eleifend elit.


</div>
```

Comment: Your code is looking very nice! Do you think it is this also to prevent user from scrolling to the first 30px?

Comment: With this code its still possible for the user to scroll back up. To prevent the user from scrolling up past a certain point, you would need to write a function that scrolls down back when the user has scrolled up a certain point.